# Parallel plate capacitor coordinate transform with a "mapping gradient"

Tags: complex-analysis

I am new to complex analysis and conformal mapping so please forgive me if my understanding is not yet there. In this [link](http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P7311fa13/Conformal.pdf) the author derives a method to express the equipotential lines and flux lines of infinite parallel plates as they would be on semi-infinite plates. The conformal mapping technique used allows the author to analyze the fringing effects on the plates.

But how would I go about mapping the flux and potential fields of two finite parallel plates to polar coordinates, as is used in a coaxial cable? The derivation is found [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1125810) but I do not understand in particular what a "mapping gradient" is, which is in the first part of the paper:

$$\frac {\partial z}{\partial w}=\frac{(w+c)(w-c)}{(w+d)(w-d)}$$

This equation expresses the gradient "between the z-plane and the w-plane." What does that mean?